# How to publish a CRM application in the CRM App Store?

Tags: web-applications, crm, publish, microsoft-dynamics, windows-store

our company would like to start developing Dynamics CRM Applications and store them in the Microsoft CRM App Store.
I looked around in the Internet but i couldn't find an exhaustive guide or some kind of suggestions to do it.
We are able to develop CRM Applications as we work on it for years, but now we want to publish (register) our apps on the store.
How we can achieve this?

Thank you in advance!!

Answer (score 1):

> To list your CRM app, please e-mail us at partners@crm-appstore.com and we will provide you with additional info and access to a self-service portal.
>
> In order to get listed your solution must be:
>
> - Available for CRM online
> - Protected by a licensing mechanism. Don’t have one? The Appstore will provide one for free
> - Updated periodically to support the latest Microsoft CRM online release

[More information](http://www.crm-appstore.com/publisherregistration)

Comment: Hi Federico, thank for your answer. I made a mistake with my question, we would like to publish it on the new Microsoft App Source, any tip?

Comment: [These](https://smp-cdn-prod.azureedge.net/documents/AppsourceGuidelines/Microsoft%20AppSource%20app%20review%20guidelines.pdf) are the guidelines but I don't have any experience with it, sorry.

Answer (score 0):

You need to Create Microsoft dev account & Azure account, 
Microsoft Dev account used for registering you or your company.

Azure account has two sites One is Portal (portal.azure.com) on which we upload the solution and get url to set on the second site of Publish(publish.azure.com) .

Publish portal you just configure your uploaded package url and dev account settings.

I have found some information from below link
http://www.axsource.com/guide-for-microsoft-partners-to-publish-app-onto-microsoft-appsource/